# Social connection requests sent to company mails, how to accept/handle them?

Tags: facebook, social-media, social-networking, linkedin

We keep getting requests from customers who want to link to us on Facebook, LinkedIn, Google+.

Even if we have fan/follow pages (they could just become fans/followers of them), most customers sends the connection requests using their accounts directly to our company mails, let's say for instance to *info@mycompany.com*, *support@mycompany.com* (which are NOT the same mails we have used to create our accounts/pages on social networks), some are even sending connection requests to our fax mail (*fax800@mycompany.com*)

Basically we go on receiving the typical messages from Facebook, LinkedIn, Google+ saying:

- *customer1@yahoo.com* is still waiting that you subscribe to Twitter
  *info@mycompany.com*
- *customer2@gmail.com* wants to remain in contact with you
  *support@mycompany.com* on LinkedIn
- and so on...

I would like not to waste all these connection requests coming from customers, **moreover not replying (or not accepting the connection) might even seem sort of rude to our customers**.

How could we accept (or handle) these request?

**Should i create a FB/LinkedIn/Twitter profile for each company mail *info@mycompany.com*, *support@mycompany.com*, *sales@mycomapny.com*? But it seems odd to me!**

Comment: depends on your needs I think

Answer (score 1):

It is against Facebook terms of service to create accounts that are not real people.  Other social networks have similar policies.  So it is not possible to create a persona (or multiple personas) for your company that can accept these requests.

On Facebook, your business presence is handled by your business's Facebook page.  You can switch to acting as your page for the purposes of posting content, liking, commenting, and sharing.  However, pages cannot accept friend requests.

With Facebook, there is not way to accept these requests within their terms of service. 
If you can email the person, you could suggest that they like your facebook page instead -- send them a link.

Twitter may be the one place that you could accept these requests.  You should be able  to click on the link in the email and then sign in using your company account to accept the request as your company.

I suspect that most of these requests come from "import my address book" uses.  The user probably didn't carefully select all the addresses that they are inviting.  As such, I don't think many users would find it rude that you don't respond.

Answer (score 0):

All of these services allow (and indeed encourage) their users to add everyone from their address book. That is likely what is happening here. Your customers have these addresses in their address books and these services are (naively) picking them up and sending out invitations to join to those addresses.

As this does not (likely) reflect an explicit action made by the user but rather a quirk of technology, you can safely ignore these requests.